# Magento2 change label of phone number field

Tags: magento-2.2.5, labels

I want to change all instances where the "phone number" field is listed to instead be labeled "Mobile Phone number" . I edited the file app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Customer/templates/widgets/telephone.phtml recompiled and redeployed however I still see the text input labeled Phone number instead of mobile phone Number ??

Where else do I need to edit this so in the frontend and backend the field is labeled as I need it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `phone number` instead `Mobile Phone number` then need to change below two file.

**1) Below CSV will translate Phone Number text in frontend address.**

> File path: magento/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/i18n/en_US.csv

`"Phone Number","Mobile Phone number"`

**2) `customer_address_form.xml` helps to translate Phone Number text in admin address.**

> File path:
>   magento/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_address_form.xml

`Change <label translate="true">Phone number</label> to <label translate="true">Mobile Phone number</label>`

```
<field name="telephone" sortOrder="130" formElement="input">
    <settings>
        <dataType>text</dataType>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <label translate="true">Mobile Phone number</label>
    </settings>
</field>
```

Run command and check.

cmd: `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Hope it help!